# How to remove charset=UTF-8 from Content-Type response header in Spring boot(v2.4.2)

Tags: java, spring-boot, mime-types

I'm trying to download a pdf file from s3 and then return a response as byte array. Everything is working find except the "Content-Type", in Content-Type the charset=UTF-8 is getting added.

I have included "spring.http.encoding.force=false" in application.properties. Below is my code snipet:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/view/{clientId}/{documentId}", produces = { "application/pdf" })
public ResponseEntity<?> downloadDocument(@PathVariable String clientId,
                                              @PathVariable String documentId) {

....
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentLength(...)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/pdf")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"inline; filename=\"download.pdf\"")
                    .body(downloadInputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

In the response log I'm getting following:

```
{
  "type": "response",
  "correlation": "e297f48c4475d510",
  "direction": "EGRESS",
  "duration": 5536,
  "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
  "status": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Keep-Alive": "timeout=360",
    "x-request-id": "e297f48c4475d510",
    "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=\"download.pdf\"",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "864038",
    "Date": "Thu, 01 Jul 2021 09:53:08 GMT",
    "Content-Type": "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try below properties?

```
server.servlet.encoding.force=false
server.servlet.encoding.forceResponse=false
```

However, both of the properties should default to false, so unless it is explicitly set to true, it won't set the encoding for you.

Another posibility is that `HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding()` is called somewhere in your code or library. You can try to debug on that method to see if any class is calling it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! One follow-up question, how can we set it to false for specific requests instead of for all APIs?

Comment: Not that I aware of, this properties control for all request/response. However you can just set `forceResponse` to false (and leave `force` to true) if you still want it apply for request.

Answer (score 0):

charset=UTF-8 is usually for plain text simple pdf files and because there is no "Content-Transfer-Encoding" the server is just assuming.
inline is load and use  ,  attachment pops a dialog box.
Page 2 and 3 in the link show how to properly set a servlet download.
http://www.windsolarhybridaustralia.x10.mx/Ramfile-html_B_.pdf

Comment: I set the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" to "binary" in the response header but no luck.

Comment: What is it that is 
serving"